# JQuery add form elements iterate ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't care about the content in the form, just want to add a new set of them every time I click add. I will however be adding some conditional fields. But with that in mind, do I actually need to iterate ids? And is the clone event the best way to handle this?

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="condition-1">
  <select id="trigger-1" class="trigger">
      <option value="0">Select...</option>
      <option value="1">View Count</option>
      <option value="2">Comment Count</option>
  </select>
  <select id="operator-1" class="operator">
      <option value="0">Select...</option>
      <option value="1">Is Greater Then</option>
      <option value="2">Less Than</option>
  </select>
  <div id="input-1" class="input">
      <input id="number-1"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="add-1" class="add">Add more</div>
```

I've been digging through a lot of examples of jQuery .clone() ,have not been able to apply any examples to a structure like this. My goal is to add a new set of form elements every time I click "Add more". I don't care if it clones the actual content, just want to clone and then iterate the id's appropriately.

I tried using something similar to:

```
var cur_num = 1;

var cloned = $("#condition-" + cur_num).clone(true, true).get(0);

++cur_num;

cloned.id = "condition-" + cur_num;                  // Change the div itself.
$(cloned).find("*").each(function(index, element) {   // And all inner elements.
    if(element.id)
    {
        var matches = element.id.match(/(.+)_\d+/);
        if(matches && matches.length >= 2)            // Captures start at [1].
            element.id = matches[1] + "-" + cur_num;
    }
});

$(cloned).appendTo($("#condition-wrapper"));*/
```

The above block of code will clone and append the block I want. But as it iterates the first condition id to #condition-2, every block after is coming up #condition-2 and I have no idea how to change the children of condition-1 to trigger-2 operator-2. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Why not just use a class and save the headache of iterating ids in the first place? It's what they were designed for.

Comment: r u particular in using .clone() itself? , means do you want to clone by .clone() event only?

Comment: Not particular about clone at all, just seemed like what people used for this. In my head, i needed to iterate ids for control when processing the form. Also, going to add some conditional fields to this, so when say View Count is selected, a different box or set of boxes may appear. If it wasn't for the conditional part I would not care about the ids at all. And even with there's probably an elegant solution to leave off the id numbers and just iterate through the ids when processing the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(function(){
$('.add').bind('click',function(){

    var $this=$(this),
        $cloned=$this.prev().clone(),
        re=/(\d+)$/,
        counter=1,
        cid=$cloned.attr('id').replace(re,function(n){
            return counter+=parseInt(n);
        });

        $cloned.attr({id:cid})
        .find('[id]')
        .each(function(i,o){
          var iid=$(o).attr('id').replace(re,counter);
          $(o).attr({id:iid});
        })
        .end()
        .insertBefore($this);
});
})
```